# Wordpress Editor without the backend

Tags: wordpress

I have a odd question, lets say I create a new section in the backend of wordpress called "Favorite Foods" with the fields "Location, "Food", "Verified". People that register to my site will become editors but instead of being directed to the back end are redirected to a page with fill in forms for the same information as the section labeled "Favorite Foods" except the "verified" boolean item. Can these editors fill in this information from those pages I create and populate that section in wordpress? If so approve/denying them should be with just a yes/no edit. But if this is possible can someone point me in the direction of some help with linking form's to wordpress sections.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar more than a year ago, where users could post their company as a new WordPress item. The way I've done it is like this:

- Create an edit page for the users to fill in information about the item, using page templates for example
- In your `functions.php` create a function that runs, if there's any post data sent
- Use [wp_insert_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to create a new item, preferably as your custom post type
- Insert the post as `pending`, so that new posts don't get published immediately

That way, you can approve new posts from the backend. Also your users don't need to have "editor" status/userrole (you don't want to do that!!).

Giving users access to the backend is a pretty delicate topic. Be sure to read about [nonces](http://codex.wordpress.org/Wordpress_Nonce_Implementation) and implement something like a captcha, to provide basic security and avoid spamming.

Answer (score 0):

I did a project using front end editors. You have to maintain the access permissions (Role management)
as @martinczerwi also said same.

### This is sample of my code please get idea from id,I suppose you understand the coding

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {
    $cpostStatus = 'draft';
    if(isset($_POST['proStatus'])){
        $cpostStatus = trim($_POST['proStatus']);
    }
    if(trim($_POST['projectName']) == '') {
        $projectNameError = 'Please enter a Project Name.';
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $projectName = trim($_POST['projectName']);
    }




    if(!$hasError){
        $post_information = array(
        'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['projectName'])),
        'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['projectDescription'])),
        'post-type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => $cpostStatus
        );

        **$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);**

        if($post_id)
        {

            // Update Custom Meta - your custom data
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'citerp_start_date', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['startDate'])));

            // Redirect
            wp_redirect( home_url('/projects') ); exit;
        }

    }

}
```

### **Same as insert use update section**

```
$post_information = array(
        'ID' => $current_post,
        'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['projectName'])),
        'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['projectDescription'])),
        'post-type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => $cpostStatus
    );

    $post_id = wp_update_post($post_information);
```